# How to change button caption when div tag is visible using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this Javascript and HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <button type="button"  onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-block btn-success"><i class="fas fa-search"></i> View Result</button>
</div>

<div id="myDIV" style="display:none">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
 }
</script>
```

By default, myDiv div tag is hidden. Then when the button is clicked it becomes visible, when it's clicked again it hides the div.

But beyond this, what I want is that when the div tag is visible the button caption should be

> Hide Result

and when the div tag is hidden, the button caption should be

> View Result

How do I modify ny current code to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: if you choose give an `id` to the button directly instead of surrounding the caption in a span, don't forget to add the icon in the innerHTML when you update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just surround the button caption in a `<span>` tag with an id :

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <button type="button"  onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-block btn-success">
    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    <span id="button-caption">View Result</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

And update the caption at the same time as you update the div visibility :

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  var y = document.getElementById("button-caption");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    y.innerHTML = "Hide Results";
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    y.innerHTML = "Show Results";
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, give your button an ID.

```
<button id="myButton" type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-block btn-success"><i class="fas fa-search"></i> View Result</button>
```

After that, in `myFunction()`, simply apply `document.getElementById("myButton").innerHTML = "New caption here"` wherever you want to change the caption.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the textContent of the button when you show/hide the div

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  var y = document.getElementById("btn");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    y.textContent = "Hide Result";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    y.textContent = "View Result";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <button id="btn" type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-block btn-success"><i class="fas fa-search"></i> View Result</button>
</div>

<div id="myDIV" style="display:none">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>
```